# ActionBar.setDefaultDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled can only be called from within the same library group (groupId=androidx.appcompat)

Tags: android, androidx

I got this error.

> ActionBar.setDefaultDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled can only be called from
>   within the same library group (groupId=androidx.appcompat)

I using androidx, and the error show when I try to setDefaultDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled on actionBar

```
setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
supportActionBar.setDefaultDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
```

My layout:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        tools:context=".ui.backdrop.BackdropActivity">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewPager"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: You want the `setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled()` method instead; no `Default`.

Comment: Yes, it is my mistake. I don't pay attention on "Default"!!!